# Including novalidate attribute into Symfony2 twig template

Tags: html, validation, symfony, twig

I am trying to disable the HTML5 validation of my form and I have seen I can include the novalidate into the form tag however I am using

```
{{ form_start(contact) }}
{{ form_end(contact) }}
```

to create my forms.

Now from the what I have been reading I should be able to include an attribute into the form_start such that the code would give me this

```
{{ form_start(contact, {'attr' : {'novalidate'}})
```

This however is not working...does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 30):

You need a key/value pair:

```
{{ form_start(contact, {attr: {novalidate: 'novalidate'}}) }}
```

Comment: hi, thanks that worked. I did actually get it working with novalidate: true as well.

Comment: Jep, but true is not the expected value in some browsers. `{novalidate: 'novalidate'}` will result in html `novalidate="novalidate"` which should be recognised by every html5 ready browser.

Comment: Yea, it doesn't really matter which value you use but it's an HTML convention to use the same value as the name of an attribute.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add `novalidate`in all the forms of your app, create a twig template like this:

```
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{# FORM START #}
{% block form_start %}
<form  action="{{ action }}"{% for attrname, attrvalue in attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}{% if multipart %} enctype="multipart/form-data"{% endif %} novalidate>
{% endblock form_start %}
```

[Documentation: Form Theme](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)

Answer (score 2):

You can set form novalidate attribute to symfony 2 form object like this

```
$form = $this->createForm(new ClientType(), $clientEntity, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('client_create'),
    'method' => 'POST',
    'attr'=>array('novalidate'=>'novalidate') //add novalidate attribute to form
));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use function `createFormBuilder()->setAttributes()` to set any attributes to the whole form, including `novalidate`:

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('value', IntegerType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save',))
        ->setAttributes(array(
            'novalidate'=>'novalidate',
            ))
        ->getForm();
```